# How to get the primary key to execute an update statement

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I'm trying to update my table using Java JDBC. But I don't have any idea how can I call my Primary Key using Prepared Statement. I try to make an `USER_ID` object for the column of my database but don't know where to start. How will I determine if I already updated my database?

**CODE**

```
String updateEmployee = employeeTf.getText();
String updateDepartment = departmentTf.getText();

if(updateEmployee.isEmpty() && updateDepartment.isEmpty()){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You didn't update it");
}
else if(updateEmployee.isEmpty()){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please update your name");
}
else if(updateDepartment.isEmpty()){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please update your department");
}
else{
    String updateQuery = "UPDATE SAMPLE SET EMPLOYEENAME = ?, DEPARTMENT = ? WHERE USER_ID = ?";

    try(Connection con = DBUtilities.getConnection(DBType.JDBC);
        PreparedStatement myPs = con.prepareStatement(updateQuery);){


        myPs.setString(1, employeeTf.getText());
        myPs.setString(2, departmentTf.getText());
        myPs.setInt(3, "WHAT GOES HERE");
        //Execute insert SQL Statement
        myPs.executeUpdate();
        System.out.print("Updated");
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        DBUtilities.processException(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking, maybe you should rephrase

Comment: Check your database to see if it's updated. I hope that's what you meant.
Refer this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: No I didn't run my database. Because for in my index 3. I dont know which will I do first so I can execute my query. Do I need to wrap my whole code with return type? Thanks.

Comment: If you are talking about logged in user id then you can use session to get user id or if you are talking about employee user id then it should be inside your employeeTf please check your database again or post your whole code

Comment: How is this not a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35765398/java-jdbc-how-to-get-the-primary-key-to-execute-an-update-statement ?

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing an UPDATE the record must already exist in your table.
Roughly your application needs the following process:

1. Read the record from the database
2. Put data from the record into your GUI controls and also **keep the ID value somewhere**.
3. Now the user hits "Save": You transfer the values from GUI controls into your PreparedStatement and use the ID from step 2 to build the where parameter.
4. Commit.

If you want to create a new record, you skip step 1 and therefore have no ID value.
Then instead of doing an UPDATE in step 3 you will need to do a INSERT.

Answer (score 0):

I think the employeeIf object should have a method like getUserId() to return the UserId of the the employee. I am not sure how did you build this employeeIf object but it always should have some method to get the userId of the employee. SO the
myPs.setInt(3, "WHAT GOES HERE"); 
should look like
myPs.setInt(3, employeeTf.getUserId());

Comment: So if I made I method will I wrap the whole code? Thanks.