# How to get the primary key to execute an select statement

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jdbc

I'm trying to update my table using Java JDBC. But I don't have any idea how can I call my primary key using prepared statement. I try to make an `USER_ID` object for the column of my database but don't know how where to start. How will I determine if I already updated my Database?

**INSERT**

```
   private void addBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
   String inputEmployee = employeeTf.getText();
   String inputDepartment = departmentTf.getText();

   if(inputEmployee.isEmpty() && inputDepartment.isEmpty()){
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please fill up!");
    }
    else if(inputEmployee.isEmpty()){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter your username");
    }
    else if(inputDepartment.isEmpty()){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter your password");
    }
    else{
        String myQuery = "INSERT INTO SAMPLE (EMPLOYEENAME,DEPARTMENT) VALUES (?,?)";

        try(Connection con = DBUtilities.getConnection(DBType.JDBC);
        PreparedStatement myPs = con.prepareStatement(myQuery);
            ){

            myPs.setString(1, employeeTf.getText());
            myPs.setString(2, departmentTf.getText());

            myPs.executeUpdate();

            System.out.print("Record is inserted");


        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            DBUtilities.processException(ex);
       }
    }
   }
```

Here if I insert a new value it will load the new values to database.

**SELECT**

```
private void searchBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
String searchEmployee = searchName.getText(); //SWING COMPONENTS
String searchDept = searchDepartment.getText();//SWING COMPONENTS

    String selectQuery = "SELECT EMPLOYEENAME,DEPARTMENT FROM SAMPLE WHERE USER_ID = ?";

    try {
        Connection con = DBUtilities.getConnection(DBType.JDBC);
        PreparedStatement myPs = con.prepareStatement(selectQuery,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE,ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE);

        ResultSet myRs = myPs.executeQuery();

        while(myRs.next()){
           String name = myRs.getString(1);
           String department = myRs.getString(2);
        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        DBUtilities.processException(ex);
    }
  }
```

**SCREENSHOT**

[image: Screenshot]

After filling out the fields for **searchName and searchDepartment textfields**. As you can see here I here hit the "Search" button. 
I want the value of **searchName and searchDepartment** will print out to the textfield of **employeeTf and departmentTf** 
How will I use the setText here?

Comment: post your swing component defination

Comment: Already edited the swing components. Thanks. Please check my post again.

Answer (score 1):

```
 while(myRs.next()){
    String name = myRs.getString(1);
    String department = myRs.getString(2);
    nameText.setText(name);
    deptText.setText(department);
 }
```

i supposed `nameText` and `deptText` are the object of swing text component

if these are not accessible here..then you can create object of all field and put data from result set and return the object and use there.

Comment: I create a object for nameText and deptText. When I try to use setText() it cannot find the symbol? Did I miss something?

Comment: post the code of swing component

Comment: Already edited. I just use drag and drop to this. For sample purposes. I know I'm already near to my answer.

Comment: have you tried this:         nameText.setText(name);

Comment: Yes but when I tried to create a object for nameText the setText will throw me an error cannot find symbol. method setText(String)